# MySQL DB views: Do both tables need to have the same name?

Tags: mysql, view

I know how to use a view of *example_table* in *example_table* in a second DB. Can a view of *example_table* be used in *different_example_table*?

Do both tables need to have the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VIEW` is just a special kind of object that holds a query.

So you can give it any syntactically correct name you want